# Navigation Drawer and Page Viewer in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, swipeview

**EDIT :**

After the recommendation of using TabStrip instead, I have been searching for it and I decided to used it instead of I was trying to do.
So the problem is still the same but different code:
In my navigation drawer I have a switch, which gives a `Fragment fragment` a Fragment value, and when I extend my `TodayFragment` with `FragmentActivity` I can´t make the last assignment because it throws a type mismatch error.

So here is part of the code (TodayFragment is now TodayFrag because I'm trying things without erasing classes):

```
Fragment fragment = null;
switch (position) {
case 0:
    fragment = new HomeFragment();
    break;
case 1:
    fragment = new TimetablesFragment();
    break;
case 2:
    fragment = new SubjectsFragment();
    break;
case 3:
    fragment = new TodayFrag();
    break;
case 4:
    fragment = new Others2Fragment();
    break;

default:
    break;
}
```

And now I have my PagerTabStrib from http://blog.pboos.ch/android-pagertabstrip-viewpager/ class:

public class TodayFrag extends FragmentActivity {}

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have my navigation drawer done, and in a certain point, i switch a position variable to determine which fragment I need to set in the view:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
switch (position) {
case 0:
    fragment = new HomeFragment();
    break;
case 1:
    fragment = new OneFragment();
    break;
case 2:
    fragment = new TwoFragment();
    break;
case 3:
    fragment = new TodayFragment();
    break;
case 4:
    fragment = new Others2Fragment();
    break;

default:
    break;
}
```

All fragments are classes that just extends Fragment except for TodayFragment(). TodayFragment() extends Fragment and implements ActionBar.TabListener because I'm trying to achieve a tab swipeable view in one of the fragments of the Navigation drawer:

```
public class TodayFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {}
```

The problem comes in the first part of the code, it says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from TodayFragment to Fragment"

I don't know too much Java, and I'm stuck.

I hope someone could help

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the piece of code where the problem occurs ?!

Comment: It is posted, it is the first big part of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said Myanimal in his answer's comments, I think you have imported different classes of `Fragment`.

- this `android.app.Fragment`
- and this `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

The `ActionBar.TabListener` you implemented or the `TabStrip` you are using are not the causes of the issue.

When an `A` class `extends/implements` a `B` class, the `A` class (the subclass) has the `"same"` properties as `B` (the base class):

`public class A extends B`  ==>  `B b = new A();` ***is possible***.

So try to remove all your `imports` and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to organize the imports. Then chose the same class of Fragments. The issue may disappear.

Comment: So, I did everything you said but I've changed the ActionBar.TabListener because I want to use TabStrip but this one uses FragmentActivity and I can't manage to make it work; I willedit and update the question so it can be understood easily.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach for tabs in a Fragment is to use a combination of `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip` as per the example at http://blog.pboos.ch/android-pagertabstrip-viewpager/

Keep in mind that `ViewPager` is from the support library, so you'll also have to use Fragments from the support library.

---

*Original (incorrect) answer:*

You need to cast your `TodayFragment` to a `Fragment`:

```
fragment = (Fragment) new TodayFragment();
```

Comment: `TodayFragment` already extends `Fragment`, no need to cast it again !

Comment: You're right. Not sure what I was thinking. He may be importing different ```Fragment``` classes in his activity and ```TodayFragment``` (native fragment vs support fragment). Just a guess though.

Comment: Not that, I have tried that just in case, but it doesn't fix anything. I think the error can come because of the implements part, but not sure how to make it work

Comment: I usually use a ```ViewPager``` with a ```PagerTabStrip``` when I want tabs in a Fragment. Not familiar with the ```ActionBar.TabListener```.

Comment: could you give me more information about it? Maybe I can change it

Comment: That example is really good, I think that even better than what I was trying to do. But I think that extending FragmentActivity will make that the app keeps throwing the same error :S

Comment: @myanimal yes I think it's due to that. So please update your answer ! The downvotes will disapear automatically :)